Expo React Native : Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information
I can't build my application with expo for android. Everything works fine on emulators.
I launch the command line
eas build -p android --profile preview

With this config in my file eas.json
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  }
}

I get this error in expo console
> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
"Install CMake 3.22.1 v.3.22.1" finished.
> Task :react-native-ad-manager:extractReleaseAnnotations
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 26s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
370 actionable tasks: 370 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

When I check with this command line
npx expo-doctor

My dependencies everything seems correct
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check native tooling versions
✔ Check if the project meets version requirements for submission to app stores
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check for app config fields that may not be synced in a non-CNG project
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check for issues with metro config
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Didn't find any issues with the project!

My app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Breathe",
    "slug": "Breathe",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#2196F3"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.mergelight.breathe"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mergelight.breathe"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-secure-store",
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}

Can you help me get my android build ?
Thx

I managed to get my build by creating a new project and moving the sources from my old project to the new one.
Could someone explain to me ? I'm curious

Ask a separate question for this, as this is neither an answer, not something pertaining to your currently asked question.
